# Lou Gehrig and Wally Pip

Tags: baseball, mlb

The story goes that Wally Pip, the Yankees 1st baseman, was sick one day and had to sit out a game. The backup, Lou Gehrig played that day and never sat again. I have 2 questions.  What is the actual historical recap of why Gehrig replaced Wally Pip and what was Gehrig's performance that first day to convince the manager to keep playing him over Wally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, he started on June 2, 1925 in place of the slumping Wally Pipp as part of a larger lineup shakeup.

I don't know that there is any record of *why* Miller Huggins stuck with Gehrig instead of putting Pipe back at 1B. It is worth noting, though, that Gehrig went 3-5 in the first game of the streak. The Yankees, who were 15-26 after losing on June 1, won 5 of their next 7 games, which was probably enough to convince Huggins that the shakeup was at least not hurting the team. During that stretch, Gehrig hit .286, while Pipp was only batting .244 up until that point.

For the rest of June, the Yankees went 14-12, with Gehrig hitting .348. Given that Pipp was 32, Gehrig was only 22, and the Yankees were not that good in 1925 (their June success was not replicated in July or August, and they finished in next-to-last place with a record of 69-85), it seems clear that Gehrig played at least well enough to earn the starting job, even if not yet the Hall-of-Famer he would become.